# Cookies.get function for js-cookie is returning an old value after being reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, js-cookie

So I am using js-cookie in a webapplication to which I'm using it to set a jwt token. My login function does Cookies.remove('jwt') before calling the axios post for the login and in the response I Cookies.set('jwt', token,{expires:1});

Within the app the api I am calling Cookies.get('jwt'); but it is referencing a previous token from before logging in.

I check the application tab and don't see a previous reference of the old token in the cookies, I checked the documentation but is there anything that I am missing I am not sure why the old token is being used.

Comment: In my experience with this issue (not surprisingly came up with JWT as well), you need to have the server tell the client to remove the cookie by adding an "Expires=" segment to the cookie (with the date being one that has already passed so that the client immediately removes it). This also means that in my JWT/SPA driven app, a page refresh is required to logout.

Comment: Does the Cookiees.remove() need to have the expires object to be able to actually remove it?

Comment: No, you can't use `Cookies.remove` at all, it's running on the client side (EDIT: Assuming your server isn't a node.js server that is also using `js-cookie`). The code you need to write is on the server side. (I can't recall exactly why the client wasn't removing the cookie, but I believe it had something to do with me using SecureCookies or something like that)